# How to link my while loop with a previous code and return the values of the first loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

So i am trying to make the tictactoe game as i started learning python a week ago and i cant seem to understand how to connect a while loop with previous code. So for example i was able to create the board,  the player enters X or O but when it starts looping and verifies the statement : while .. > ..: it asks to enter a number from 1-9 and it resets and only shows the new input but not the old one + the new one.Watched a few videos and read some info about while loops in Python crash course but the are all the same and i get how to break or continue a loop, its just i cant seem to 'save' the previous one since it overwrites

```
player1_ox = input("Player 1 insert X or O")
player2_ox = ''
player1_num = int()
player2_num = int()

number_moves = 0
while number_moves < 9:
  if player1_ox in 'Xx':
    player2_ox = 'O'
  elif player1_ox in 'Oo':
    player2_ox = 'X'
  print("player 1 choice = ", player1_ox.upper(), "\n", "player 2 choice = ", player2_ox)


  player1_num = int(input("insert number 1 - 9"))
  player2_num = int(input("insert number 1-9"))

  n_even = list(range(1,18, 2))
  n_odd = list(range(0, 23, 2))
  n_total = ''
  for i in range(len(n_even)):
    if player1_num == i:
      n_odd[i] = player1_ox.upper()
      n_even[i] = '|'
      n_total += n_even[i] + n_odd[i]
    elif player2_num == i:
      n_even[i] = '|'
      n_odd[i] = player2_ox.upper()
      n_total += n_even[i] + n_odd[i]
    else:
      n_even[i] = '|'
      n_odd[i] = '_'
      n_total += n_even[i] + n_odd[i]

  number_moves += 2

  print(n_total[0:6])
  print(n_total[6:12])
  print(n_total[12:18])
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your immediate question ...

Your board doesn't keep previous moves because you painstakingly erase and rebuild the board after each pair of moves.  You need to apply a basic principle of loops: things that get done for each move go inside the loop; things that get done only once go outside the loop.

In this case, you need to set up the loop format *before* the loop, doing it only once.  Then, simply insert the new moves by changing individual characters.

You've also made this harder than necessary, by setting up lists instead of formatting your output.  You don't need a list with vertical bars to make this work; just stick in the liter character as needed.

Without changing your code too much let's attack the information basis: you need to maintain an indicator for each of nine locations.  Let's simplify your three lists to a simple string, starting as "_________", a string of nine underscores, an empty board.

Now, when a player chooses a location, insert their token into the spot on the board.  To make it easier, arbitrarily assign `X` to player1.  Now ...

```
board = "_________"
while ... 
    ...
    board[player1_num-1] = `X`
    board[player2_num-1] = `O`
    ...
    print("{}|{}|{}\n{}|{}|{}\n{}|{}|{}\n".format(*board))
```

Sample output, given board = 'O_X_X_OXO'

```
O|_|X
_|X|_
O|X|O
```